# setInterval for jQuery for loop trouble

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, timer, setinterval

I am trying to run a specific for loop every x seconds, but cannot seem to make `setInterval work. I am sure my syntax is incorrect, yet, I cannot seem to get it right.

I have added my full code below:

**jQuery:**

```
//Click saves this.id as userID
$(function() {
  var rTitle, rText, qTitle, qText, numRows, userID;
  $("#buttons").find(".btn").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('fullscreen');
    $(this).parent().siblings().toggleClass('master');
    var userID = this.id;

    //userID is then used for ajax to PHP script, information passed back is put in variables and generateProblems function is run
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'include/responseget.php',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        userID: userID
      },
      success: function(json) {
        rTitle = json.rTitle;
        rText = json.rText;
        qTitle = json.qTitle;
        qText = json.qText;
        next = json.next;
        numRows = json.numRows;
        id = json.id;
        generateProblems();
      }
    });

  });
  //Generate draggable html with an interval of 1000
  function generateProblems() {
    $('<div>' + qTitle + '</div>').data('number', qTitle).attr('id', 'question').attr('class', 'bold').appendTo($("#" + id).parent()).hide().fadeIn(2000);
    for (var i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
      setInterval(function() {
        $('<div>' + rTitle[i] + '</div>').data('number', next[i]).attr('id', +next[i]).appendTo($("#" + id).parent()).draggable({
          containment: '.site-wrapper',
          stack: '#testpile div',
          cursor: 'move',
          revert: true
        }).hide().fadeIn(2000)
        $('<div>' + rText[i] + '</div>').data('number', next[i]).attr('id', +next[i]).appendTo($("#" + id).parent()).hide().fadeIn(2000);
      }, 1000);
    }

   //Rest of the code is not important, but I put it in nonetheless.
    $('#testdrop').droppable({
      drop: handleDropEvent,
      accept: '#testpile div'
    });

    function handleDropEvent(event, ui) {
      var problemNumber = ui.draggable.data('number');
      ui.draggable.draggable('disable');
      ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', false);
      $("#testpile").children().hide();

      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'include/responseget.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
          userID: problemNumber
        },
        success: function(json) {
          rTitle = json.rTitle;
          rText = json.rText;
          qTitle = json.qTitle;
          qText = json.qText;
          next = json.next;
          numRows = json.numRows;
          generateProblems();
        }
      });

    }
  }
});
```

**PHP:**

```
<?php  include 'login.php';
    if(isset($_POST['userID'])){
        $id = $_POST['userID'];
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT AnswerTitle, AnswerText, QuestionTitle, QuestionText, Next FROM question_answers
        INNER JOIN question
        ON question_answers.QuestionID=question.QuestionID
        INNER JOIN answer
        ON question_answers.AnswerID=answer.AnswerID
        WHERE AnswerGroup = ?;");
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $id);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();

          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
          {
              $rTitle_array[] = $row['AnswerTitle'];
              $rText_array[] = $row['AnswerText'];
              $qTitle = $row['QuestionTitle'];
              $qText = $row['QuestionText'];
              $next_array[] = $row['Next'];
              $numRows = ($result->num_rows);
          }

        $response = array(
            'rTitle' => $rTitle_array,
            'rText'  => $rText_array,
            'qTitle' => $qTitle,
            'qText'  => $qText,
            'next'  => $next_array,
            'numRows'  => $numRows,
            'id'  => $id
        );

        echo json_encode($response);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Please note you are running multiple (`numrows`) setInterval timer and not just one setInterval timer as you should do.

Comment: You're not running one thing at a given interval. You're launching as many intervals as you get rows. So if you have 10 rows, you will launch 10 intervals, all running concurrently.

Comment: Ah, see, that's not what I am trying to achieve, I am seeking to run 1 interval at a time and generate the html for each row, 1 after another. It's clear that I have put setInterval the wrong place, as well as use the wrong syntax. Got any idea for a solution? Also, thanks for pointing out the problem to me.

Comment: So you want it to add one row at a time to the table? For what purpose? What effect are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: To the table? I'm a little confused about that, but I'm assuming that you mean the div I'm appending this query information to. What I am trying to do is to add them to my parent div, one by one, fading in. So instead of them all fading in at the same time, they are faded in, one by one. I'm doing this to create the pretend effect to the user, that they are being generated one by one. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *sounds* like you're trying to get this effect of adding one row every second. You could use recursion.

Also, `setInterval` is for numerous calls. `setTimeout` is for a single call.

```
function generateProblems(i)
{
    // if we're at the end then stop
    if(i == numRows) return;

    // wait 1000
    setTimeout(function()
    {
        // do what you want with i here

        // call the next iteration
        generateProblems(i + 1);
    }, 1000);
}

// then you kick it off with the 0 index
generateProblems(0);
```

Or if you want the first iteration to kick off immediately:

```
function generateProblems()
{
    // if we're at the end then stop
    if(i == numRows) return;

    // do what you want with i here

    // move to next row
    ++i;
    setTimeout(generateProblems, 1000);
}

// global var to keep track of where we are
i = 0;
generateProblems
```

Comment: That does indeed seem to be what I am trying to do - your first suggestion, that is. Problem is, I am failing to make it work for some reason. Should I post my attempt as a comment here? Cause your explanation is pretty throughout, but I must be getting something wrong. Also, thank you for your help and time.

Comment: Scratch that, I got it working, thank you very much!

Comment: If you don't want it to happen 1 after the other, then you could put it in a for loop too. Not sure what that'll do to performance if you have a lot of `numRows`.

Comment: I have max 8 rows for each query, so that should not become a problem. I have however a step in my script that I do not want repeated more than once, but still want as part of my generateProblems function, how would you go about doing that? Just an if sentence with the (i == 0)?